# How to reposition a circle to be outside of circumference of two other circles?

Tags: unity-game-engine, math

This is a question for Unity people or Math geniuses.

I'm making a game where I have a circle object that I can move, but I don't want it to intersect or go into other (static) circles in the world (Physics system isn't good enough in Unity to simply use that, btw).

It's in 3D world, but the circles only ever move on 2 axis.

I was able to get this working perfectly if circle hits only 1 other circle, but not 2 or more.

FYI: All circles are the same size.

Here's my working formula for 1 circle to move it to the edge of the colliding circle if intersecting:

```
newPosition = PositionOfStaticCircleThatWasJustIntersected + ((positionCircleWasMovedTo - PositionOfStaticCircleThatWasJustIntersected).normalized * circleSize);
```

But I can't figure out a **formula if the moving circle hits 2 (or more) static circles at the same time.**

One of the things that confuse me the most is the direction issue depending on how all the circles are positioned and what direction the moving circle is coming from.

Here's an example image of what I'm trying to do.

[image: Example of what I'm trying to calculate.]

Comment: Just to clarify: is the moved circle supposed to be "pushed out" in just any direction or does it need to still move on the original vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we're operating in a 2D space, let's approach this with some geometry. Taking a close look at your desired outcome, a particular shape become apparent:

[image]

There's a triangle here! And since all circles are the same radius, we know even more: this is an isosceles triangle, where two sides are the same length. With that information in hand, the problem basically boils down to:

[image]

We know what *d* is, since it's the distance between the two circles being collided with. And we know what *a* is, since it's the radius of all the circles. With that information, we can figure out where to place the moved circle. We need to move it *d/2* between the two circles (since the point will be equidistant between them), and *h* away from them.

Calculating the height *h* is straightforward, since this is a right-angle triangle. According to the Pythagorean theorem:

```cs
// a^2 + b^2 = c^2, or rewritten as:
// a = root(c^2 - b^2)
float h = Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(2 * a, 2) - Mathf.Pow(d / 2, 2))
```

Now need to turn these scalar quantities into vectors within our game space. For the vector between the two circles, that's easy:

```cs
Vector3 betweenVector = circle2Position - circle1Position
```

But what about the height vector along the *h* direction? Well, since all movement is on 2D space, find a direction that your circles don't move along and use it to get the cross product (the perpendicular vector) with the `betweenVector` using [Vector3.Cross()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Cross.html). For
example, if the circles only move laterally:

```cs
Vector3 heightVector = Vector3.Cross(betweenVector, Vector3.up)
```

Bringing this all together, you might have a method like:

```cs
Vector3 GetNewPosition(Vector3 movingCirclePosition, Vector3 circle1Position,
    Vector3 circle2Position, float radius)
{
    float halfDistance = Vector3.Distance(circle1Position, circle2Position) / 2;
    float height = Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(2 * radius, 2) - Mathf.Pow(halfDistance, 2));

    Vector3 betweenVector = circle2Position - circle1Position;
    Vector3 heightVector = Vector3.Cross(betweenVector, Vector3.up);    

    // Two possible positions, on either side of betweenVector
    Vector3 candidatePosition1 = circle1Position
        + betweenVector.normalized * halfDistance
        + heightVector.normalized * height;
    Vector3 candidatePosition2 = circle1Position
        + betweenVector.normalized * halfDistance
        - heightVector.normalized * height;

    // Absent any other information, the closer position will be assumed as correct
    float distToCandidate1 = Vector3.Distance(movingCirclePosition, candidatePosition1);
    float distToCandidate2 = Vector3.Distance(movingCirclePosition, candidatePosition2);
    
    if (distToCandidate1 < distToCandidate2){
        return candidatePosition1;
    }
    else{
        return candidatePosition2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty impressive answer! :) I quickly tried it tonight before going to bed and it kind of works. There might be some issues on my side, though. I'll take a look at it tomorrow and let you know. Thanks you so much for your detailed answer!

Comment: I took another look through my code and spotted some embarrassing bugs - I've fixed them now, so give it another try when you get back to this. I'll be happy to answer any questions that come up!

Comment: Thank you! I believe it works as intended now. You're a pro!